# Will strange transcript preclude the possibility of graduate school?

Tags: research-process, transcript-of-records

I am a student at a community college and I hope to eventually pursue a research career.  The issue is that I have taken classes inconsistently for personal reasons, and I fear that it may make that goal an impossibility.  I began taking classes part-time 3 years ago, at 17, and have been inconsistently taking part-time classes since then (1-3 classes per semester, not taking classes every semester).

I have struggled immensely with certain personal issues (like ADHD, depression, and addiction) over the past several years, and I'm not sure if it's possible to recover from this academic record.  And I need to learn more math before having enough remaining courses available for me to take a full load of classes.  My GPA in the classes that I have completed is 4.00, however, and I have no Ws or Fs.

If my inconsistent record precludes the possibility of graduate school/research, I have no reason to continue in this field and think it best that I drop our and instead simply focus on finding a way to make money, but I'd *really* like to pursue research.

So, am I screwed, or can I recover?

Comment: It took me four majors, three colleges, 10 years, and about 220 credit hours to finish my bachelors degree.  At the end of my first two years as an undergraduate, I had a GPA of 1.95.  I have a PhD now.  It wasn't easy, but it can be done (particularly in the US, where the system permits many second chances).

Answer (score 9):

No, being a part time student will not doom your graduate school applications especially if you have excellent grades. You will probably need to eventually transfer or enroll in a 4-year institution and succeed there, however.

To be *successful* in graduate school you will likely need to overcome some of the struggles you've had so far. I would focus on strategies to do that and continue to grow skills rather than worrying about any part time education.

To reiterate: I do not see anything in your description of your situation from an academic perspective that it is necessary to *recover* from.